# html5, javascript - Adding ability to Tweet a section of a page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I have been looking at a plug-in called TwitThis, but it is for tweeting the address/details of the page you are currently on.

What I am trying to achieve is the equivalent of this:

(obviously this is only conceptual, before anyone says 'You can't code like that you dolt!')

```
<ul>
  <li>Short section of text <tweet button> </li>
  <repeat ad nauseum>
</ul>
```

Pressing the tweet button will tweet the content of that HTML tag

It's a bit of a weird one, I know.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not like I haven't googled it already. Can't find anything, so asking knowledgable people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JS Library is necessary. Use [Twitter Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>some text</span><button>Tweet</button></li>
    <li><span>some other text</span><button>Tweet</button></li>
</ul>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+$(this).parent().find('span').text());
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNDGw/1/)